# reshape function gives "subscript out of bounds" error

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have a ROC.Value data frame that looks like this:

```
Years   1           2   3       4   5
2002    3.000000    NA  0.22    NA      0
2003    2.988000    NA  0.22    NA      0
2004    2.993976    NA  0.22    NA      0
2005    3.071819    NA  0.22    NA      NA
2006    3.314493    NA  0.22    NA      NA
2007    3.526621    NA  0.22    NA      NA
2008    3.583047    NA  0.22    NA      NA
2009    4.109754    NA  0.22    NA      NA
2010    4.085096    NA  0.22    3.00    NA
2011    3.885096    NA  0.22    2.85    NA
2012    3.685096    NA  0.22    2.70    NA
2013    3.485096    NA  0.22    2.55    NA
2014    3.285096    NA  0.22    2.40    NA
2015    3.085096    NA  0.22    2.25    NA
2016    2.885096    NA  0.22    2.10    NA
2017    2.685096    NA  0.22    1.95    NA
2018    2.485096    NA  0.22    1.80    NA
2019    2.285096    NA  0.22    1.65    NA
2020    2.085096    NA  0.22    1.50    NA
2021    1.885096    NA  0.22    1.50    NA
```

The NA values will be replaced, when i get the correct data.

When i with the following code try and converting it into long format (so i can make a stacked boxplot):

```
m.ROC.Value = reshape(ROC.Value, 
                  idvar="Years", 
                  direction="long", 
                  varying=list(colnames(ROC.Value[2:6])),
                  timevar="Characteristic"
                  )
```

I get this error `Error in reshapeLong(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying, : subscript out of bounds`.

Any suggesting? Everything I tried didn't work out (gave a new error).

Comment: Your code worked without any problems on my system.

Comment: Hmm. I am running R version 2.15.1 and reshape2 package. Is that the same as you?

Comment: I am running the same version of R. Maybe it works if you rename columns 2 to 6. It could be a problem that they start with (are) a numeral.

Comment: I've also tried this (started out with non-numerical names, and then changed it, but it didn't solving the problem). I just gives me the `subscript out of bounds` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `reshape` is a base function of R, not of `reshape2`. If you want to use `reshape2`, use this command:

```
melt(as.data.frame(ROC.Value), measure.vars = 2:6)
```

Comment: I also tried this function. But it turns all columns into measurement variables - even though i specify that it should only be columns 2:6. It looks like this: http://pastebin.com/pcnv38Gm

Comment: @bonna What is the result of `str(ROC.Value)`.

Comment: num [1:20, 1:6] 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 ...  
     - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2  
      ..$ : NULL  
      ..$ : chr [1:6] "Years" "1" "2" "3" ...

Comment: @bonna I suppose your problem can be solved if you transform `ROC.Value` into a data frame before using `melt`. See the update of my answer. I can reproduce your error message if I use `ROC.Value` as a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid work around - but it works.
Instead of adding the years column straight away, I added it after i have used the `melt()` function.

```
#Don't add years here
#ROC.Value = cbind(years, Buy.Out.Value, Recycled.Green.Premium, Levy.Exemption.Certificate, Energy.Value, CO2.Price, deparse.level = 1)
ROC.Value = cbind(Buy.Out.Value, Recycled.Green.Premium, Levy.Exemption.Certificate, Energy.Value, CO2.Price, deparse.level = 1)
m.ROC.Value = melt(ROC.Value)
#Add years here (runs from 2002, so using id+2001)
m.ROC.Value = cbind(m.ROC.Value, m.ROC.Value$Var1 + rep(2001, 100))
colnames(m.ROC.Value) = c("id", "measure", "value", "years")
```